# Node.js ejs - How to use a variable in a ejs expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using express and ejs to render my files. In a addition I render a <%= data.groupID %> which is 60113 like this:

```
<div>
    <%= data.groupID %>
</div>

<div>
    <% include docs/profile_60113 %>
</div>
```

How can I use the variable in the <% include docs/profile_GROUPID %> expression?!

```
<div>
    <script>
     var getGroupID;
     function functiongroupID() {
         getGroupID = '<%= data.groupID %>';
     }
     functiongroupID();
     console.log(getGroupID);

 </script>
</div>

<div>
    <%= data.groupID %>
</div>

<div>
    <% include docs/profile_GROUPID %>
</div>
```

Is that even possible or do I need to do an if?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax for an include](https://ejs.co/#docs) is:

```
<%- include('user/show', {user: user}); %>
```

You can just put the variable where you would normally put the string literal.

```
<%- include(variable_here, {user: user}); %>
```

And if you want to combine it with a string, you do so in any of the normal ways:

```
<%- include("docs/profile_" + GROUPID); %>
<%- include(`docs/profile_${GROUPID}`); %>
```

Obviously, `GROUPID` needs to be a variable [generated in your server-side code and not in your client-side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) since your client side `<script>` element won't run until the EJS has finished executing and the output of it sent to the browser.